# Plot graph on more than one grouped column in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, visualization

I have a scenario, where I need to visualize the below dataset.

[image]

I need to plot in such a way that it can represent top2 products per category per year.

I tried subplots, where each subplot was representing a category but I stucked to create top2 product details per year.

Added Below sample data:

```
lst = [['Life Insurance', '2012', 'mylife', '80'], ['Life Insurance', '2012', 'greaterlife', '70'], 
      ['Life Insurance', '2013', 'mylife', '50'], ['Life Insurance', '2013', 'greaterlife', '40'],
      ['Life Insurance', '2014', 'mylife', '30'], ['Term Insurance', '1999', 'newterm', '300'],
      ['Term Insurance', '1999', 'termexceeded', '210'], ['Term Insurance', '2013', 'newterm', '200'],
      ['Term Insurance', '2013', 'termexceeded', '150'], ['Term Insurance', '2016', 'newterm', '30']] 
    
df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns =['Category', 'Year', 'Top2 Products', 'amount']) 
df
```

```
Category    Year    Top2 Products   amount
0   Life Insurance  2012    mylife  80
1   Life Insurance  2012    greaterlife 70
2   Life Insurance  2013    mylife  50
3   Life Insurance  2013    greaterlife 40
4   Life Insurance  2014    mylife  30
5   Term Insurance  1999    newterm 300
6   Term Insurance  1999    termexceeded    210
7   Term Insurance  2013    newterm 200
8   Term Insurance  2013    termexceeded    150
9   Term Insurance  2016    newterm 30
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data to work with?  Also, what is it that you want to plot, just the product names or is there some numeric column missing too?

Comment: @tania I want to plot top2 products for each category of each year. This is grouped data for your reference. I am finding top 2 products based on amount field just in case you want to use it in some or the other way.